# how do get the speicific results in strings python?

Tags: python

Modify the double_word function so that it returns the same word repeated twice, followed by the length of the new doubled word. For example, double_word("hello") should return hellohello10.

```
def double_word(word): return 
print(double_word("hello")) # Should return hellohello10
print(double_word("abc")) # Should return abcabc6
print(double_word(""))  # Should return 0
```

Comment: This sounds like a homework problem. On this site, when discussing such problems, you need to show what you tried.

Comment: ok, what's blocking you from writing that function?

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow — we expect questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems — but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this simple function:

```
def double_word(word):
   return word + word + len(word + word)
```

then go for check:

```
>>> double_word('farzad')
farzadfarzad12
```

Answer (score -1):

this will work for you.

```
def double_word(word):
    a=word+word
    a=a+str(len(a))
    return a
```

Comment: Or one line solution `return '{}{}'.format(2*word, len(word)*2)`

Comment: It seems he/she is new to python. This can confuse. One line solution is good but not for a beginner.

Comment: If he reads the documentation, this line is not a wizard trick but I guess you wanna say that is more readable by seeing each lines as a step ;)

Comment: Yes i am comnpletely new to python

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked and i understood the problem

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.